# Could not GET note.dit-inc.us/down.html android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I get this error 'Could not GET note.dit-inc.us/down.html'. Received status code 503 from server: Service Unavailable 
Enable Gradle offline mode' and sync project'
when I try make my project in android studio

Comment: add gradle log/configuration

Comment: where is gradle log/configuration?@KingStone